# Set a UITableviewcell to get notification when it becomes visible?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have some computationally intensive code that fires in uitableviewcells, but I don't want it to fire until the cell becomes visible on the iphone screen. Is there any callback I can register which would enable me to activate the code when the cell becomes visible to the user? The only solutions that I can find is code to check if a specific tableview cell is visible.

Comment: You can use cellWillDisplay delegate method of tableview.

Comment: Don't fight the framework. Consider to move the *intensive code* into the **model**.

Comment: "Consider to move the intensive code into the model" : point taken Vadian, but this is viz code inside each cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this delegate:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows?.contains(indexPath) ?? false {
        print("Cell \(indexPath.row)")
    }
    // Do something based on indexPath
}
```

However if you are trying to access the visible rows somewhere else, you can get visible rows like this

```
let visibleCells = tableView.visibleCells
```

or

```
guard let indexPathForVisibleCells = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows else {
    print("No visible cells found")
    return
}
for index in indexPathForVisibleCells {
    let cell = cellForRow(at: index)
    // Do something with cell
}
```

Comment: thanks - I believe this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Actually, this method (willDisplay) is firing 17 times for me without scrolling of the table. Wish there was a better mechanism to detect just the actual VISIBLE cells

Comment: Rakesha, that absolutely works - thank you a bunch for the code example