# Wait for UITableView to finish insert

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm trying to insert a new row, and immediately make it the first responder.

Using `.insertRows()` seems to execute asynchronously, even with `.none`. for the animation. That means that when I call `cellForRow(at:)`, it returns nil.

What would be the best way to wait for the insert to finish, before calling `becomeFirstResponder`?

This does not work:

```swift
self.tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndex], with: .none)
self.tableView.cellForRow(at: newIndex)?.becomeFirstResponder() //Returns nil
```

Comment: I think you can use ```DispatchQueue.main.async```. Put both lines inside the main queue.

Comment: This is all happening on the main thread already

Comment: then put it little delay for cellForRow line.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51815888/2567725

Comment: You probably also have to consider, that the cell returned by `self.tableView.cellForRow(at: newIndex)` is potentially not visible and therefore can not become the first responder.
Also check if you are calling something like `reloadData()` after the insert, this could reset the first responder.

Comment: Why do you have to use .insertRaws()? I mean, why you do not just call reloadData() after adding new item to array?

Comment: @winner.ktw Maybe cause he doesn't need to reload the entire table view cause he's using (batch) updates?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have to use .insertRaws()? I mean, why don't you just call reloadData() after adding new item to array?

Note: I updated the code and tested in Xcode. Thanks vadian and Will.

```
    array.append(newItem)
    tableView.reloadData()  // It is required.

    let newIndex = IndexPath(row: array.count - 1, section: 0)
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: newIndex)!
    cell.becomeFirstResponder()

    // If animation is needed
    let transition = CATransition()
    transition.type = CATransitionType.reveal
    cell.layer.add(transition, forKey: nil)
```

Comment: This cannot work. The last index of a table view is `.count - 1` and `count` is not a function.

Comment: This won't allow for animation at all

Answer (score 0):

Put the `insertRows(at:with:)` call between a `beginUpdates()` and `endUpdates()` calls:

```
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
self.tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndex], with: .none)
self.tableView.endUpdates()

self.tableView.cellForRow(at: newIndex)?.becomeFirstResponder()
```

Anyway I'm not so fond of letting as first responder a cell in this way: what if it's not visible?

Comment: It's scrolled to be visible when the keyboard pops up